# Use Font and Emphasise at the same time

Tags: fonts, fontspec, italic, emphasis

It seems that whenever I use `setmainfont(Cochin)`, all the `textbf{}`, `textit{}` in the main text will just not work. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks! I am not sure if it's because of the font.

The following is a code black:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\setmainfont{Cochin}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Hi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a small but complete document (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`), which reproduce your problem. You may have error at using `setmainfont` or this font haven't shapes used in emphasised text.

Comment: Does the `.log` file have any error messages about not being able to find Cochin Italic, or a `/m/i` version of Cochin? You’re probably on a Mac if you’re using Cochin, so Cochin Bold and Cochin Italic should be pre-installed.

Comment: @Davislor No, everything is fine. Yes, I am indeed using a Mac.

Comment: Unfortunately, since I’m not, I can’t reproduce the bug. Hope someone else can help!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE...

You have to define the roman, italic, bold and bolditalic fonts, like (I used `AdoneTextPro` as example) as below:

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Path = mention file path where you keep the fonts,
UprightFont= AdobeTextPro-Regular.otf,
BoldFont=AdobeTextPro-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont=AdobeTextPro-It.otf,
BoldItalicFont=AdobeTextPro-BoldIt.otf
]{AdobeTextPro}
\settextfont{AdobeTextPro}
```